# php png merging issue with images

Tags: php, image, png

I have two pictures I would like to merge, they are both sized 150x150 pixels.

I want to merge them into a new image, sized 225 width x 150 height. So that image 2 covers half of image 1.

I made some code, but the transparency only works on 150x150 of the new image, the rest just gets a black background.

Both images, do have transparent backgrounds.

background.png is just a png file sized 225x150 pixels, with transparent background.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$width = "225";
$height = "150";

$dest_image = imagecreatefrompng('background.png');

imagesavealpha($dest_image, true);            
$trans_background = imagecolorallocatealpha($dest_image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($dest_image, 0, 0, $trans_background);

$a = imagecreatefrompng('9.png');
$b = imagecreatefrompng('90.png');

imagecopy($dest_image, $a, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
imagecopy($dest_image, $b, 75, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest_image);

imagedestroy($a);
imagedestroy($b);
imagedestroy($dest_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imagecopy($dest_image, $a, 75, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
imagecopy($dest_image, $b, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, $height);
```

Just a position problem - fixed:)